# How can I set child div width equal to to max-width but centered of parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How to set **width** equalt to **max-width** even contents is not yet fill fully to max width of child div and child div alway **centered** of parent, but it should wrap child div (child div will width equal to parent) if parent div smaller than child div

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px dotted green;
}

.child {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
}

.expected-width {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 16px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">contents</div>
  <div class="expected-width">expected width</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add width:100% ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add width: 100% to child you'll get the same width

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px dotted green;
}

.child {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
}

.expected-width {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 16px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">contents</div>
  <div class="expected-width">expected width</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your question correctly and you want your element to have full width although it is empty from content you can do

```
.child {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  background: red;

  width: 100%; // setting 100% width with max width will always stretch the element to the max width (if possible)
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I want. Thank you so much. 